# Better way to write algorithm, possibly recursive

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I wrote the following code:

```
def find_storms_dst(d_f, max, min):
    i = 0
    storms = []
    while i < len(d_f.index):
        dst = d_f['Dst'][i]
        if dst < max:
            if dst < min:
                print 'out of range'
            s = Storm(i, d_f.index[i], dst)
            while i < len(d_f.index)-1:
                i += 1
                dst = d_f['Dst'][i]
                if dst < max:
                    if dst < min:
                        print 'out of range'
                    s.log(i, d_f.index[i], dst)
                else:
                    break
            storms.append(s)
        i += 1
    return storms
```

I does what I want. But I see some elements in it repeat, is that a recursion issue?

How one could write this better?

Comment: You should add a description of what it is the code actually does.  At the moment, we are left guessing.

Comment: "But I see some elements in it repeat, is that a recursion issue?" Does this code work the way that you want it to?

Comment: Recursion is when a method or function calls itself.  I don't see that here.  Perhaps in the larger code of which this is part.  But if so, you should include that code as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Encapsulating checking the distance

You are checking whether `dst < max` and whether `dst < min` twice with the same consequences. By encapsulating this in a short function, you can avoid redundancies and make your code more clear. Assuming that `min<max`, this function would could look like this:

```
def check_dst(i):
    dst = d_f['Dst'][i]
    if dst < min:
        print 'out of range'
    return dst < max
```

As the above function only takes an index as an argument, it would have to be defined inside of `find_storms_dst`. This has more advantages in the following steps. Even if the following steps will reduce the need for using this function twice, it still makes your code more readable (and facilitates list filtering).

Moreover, it seems likely to me that you want to do something else if `dst < min`, e.g., raising an error or at least a warning and `check_dst` should not return `True`.

## Filtering first

Your code seems to do two things:

- Finding indices from your `dst` object that complies with certain criteria.
- Doing something with those indices that do comply.

By unnecessarily intertwining those aspects, you are complicating your code. So, let’s first find the indices that comply with your criteria and call them `protostorms`. With the above definition, this is pretty straightforward:

```
protostorms = filter(check_dst, range(len(d_f.index)))
```

## Compiling the proto-storms

Now, all that remains to do is to compile the list of storms from the proto-storms. An straightforward way to do this would be popping items from your protostorms list successively like this:

```
storms = []
while protostorms:
    i = protostorms.pop(0)
    s = Storm(i, d_f.index[i], d_f['Dst'][i])

    while protostorms and protostorms[0]==i+1:
        i = protostorms.pop(0)
        s.log(i, d_f.index[i], dst)

    storms.append(s)

return storms
```

## Result

Taking all of the above together, your new code would look like this:

```
def find_storms_dst(d_f, max, min):
    def check_dst(i):
        dst = d_f['Dst'][i]
        if dst < min:
            print 'out of range'
        return dst < max

    protostorms = filter(check_dst, range(len(d_f.index)))

    storms = []
    while protostorms:
        i = protostorms.pop(0)
        s = Storm(i, d_f.index[i], d_f['Dst'][i])

        while protostorms and protostorms[0]==i+1:
            i = protostorms.pop(0)
            s.log(i, d_f.index[i], dst)

        storms.append(s)

    return storms
```

You could encapsulate the last loop, but I will leave it like this for now.

## Restructuring `d_f` and `Storm`

Another issue I noticed is that your `d_f` object seems to be structured in a cumbersome manner. To get a distance, you first have to get an index from `d_f.index` (by the way: Shouldn’t this be named `d_f.indices`?), which you then have to feed into `d_f['Dst']`. Also `Storm` and `log` take multiple properties from some element of `d_f`, which could be streamlined.

If you can, I recommend changing `d_f` such that it is an iterable of objects – let’s call them *events* –, which are accepted as an input by `Storm` and `log` and have an index and a distance as properties. Your code could then look like something along the line of the following:

```
def find_storms_dst(d_f, max, min):
    def check_dst(event):
        if event.dst < min:
            print 'out of range'
        return event.dst < max

    def adjacent(storm, protostorm):
        return storm.last_index() == protostorm.index

    protostorms = filter(check_dst, d_f)

    storms = []
    while protostorms:
        s = Storm(protostorms.pop(0))
        while protostorms and adjacent(s, protostorms[0]):
            s.log(protostorms.pop(0))
        storms.append(s)

    return storms
```